# Футер не привязывается к концу страницы

Tags: html, css

В мобильном режиме футер поднимается над основным контентом

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round|Work+Sans&display=swap');

/*  */

* {
 outline: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 color: #6393ec;
 background-color: #35373d;
}

input[type='button'],
label {
 cursor: pointer;
}

nav {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

article {
 height: 100vh;
}

footer,
header {
 padding-left: 5%;
 user-select: none;
 background-color: red;
}

header {
 padding-bottom: 70px;
 padding-top: 70px;
}

footer {
 /* width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0; */
 color: #6e6f72;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
 padding-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, height: device-height, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <noscript><h1>Turn on javascript support</h1></noscript>
  <div class="container">
   <article>
    Равным образом высокотехнологичная концепция общественной системы способствует подготовке и реализации соответствующих условий активизации. Не следует, однако, забывать, что управление и развитие структуры играет важную роль в формировании укрепления демократической системы. Для современного мира социально-экономическое развитие обеспечивает широкому кругу специалистов модели развития. Не вызывает сомнений, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий играет важную роль в формировании системы обучения кадров, соответствующей насущным потребностям. Задача организации, в особенности же курс на социально-ориентированный национальный проект требует определения и уточнения поставленных обществом и правительством задач. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также управление и развитие структуры играет важную роль в формировании систему массового участия. Следует отметить, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий обеспечивает актуальность направлений прогрессивного развития. С другой стороны повышение уровня гражданского сознания позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке форм воздействия. Прежде всего социально-экономическое развитие позволяет оценить значение представляет собой интересный эксперимент системы обучения кадров, соответствующей насущным потребностям. С другой стороны сложившаяся структура организации требует анализа новых предложений.Равным образом высокотехнологичная концепция общественной системы способствует подготовке и реализации соответствующих условий активизации. Не следует, однако, забывать, что управле
   </article>
   <footer>
    <p id="copyright" class="content flex">© 123123</p>
   </footer>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  color: #6393ec;
  background-color: #35373d;
}

input[type='button'],
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

article {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer,
header {
  padding-left: 5%;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: red;
}

header {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  color: #6e6f72;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  padding-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<noscript>
    <h1>Turn on javascript support</h1>
  </noscript>
<article>
  Равным образом высокотехнологичная концепция общественной системы способствует подготовке и реализации соответствующих условий активизации. Не следует, однако, забывать, что управление и развитие структуры играет важную роль в формировании укрепления
  демократической системы. Для современного мира социально-экономическое развитие обеспечивает широкому кругу специалистов модели развития. Не вызывает сомнений, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий играет важную роль в формировании системы обучения
  кадров, соответствующей насущным потребностям. Задача организации, в особенности же курс на социально-ориентированный национальный проект требует определения и уточнения поставленных обществом и правительством задач. Идейные соображения высшего порядка,
  а также управление и развитие структуры играет важную роль в формировании систему массового участия. Следует отметить, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий обеспечивает актуальность направлений прогрессивного развития. С другой стороны повышение
  уровня гражданского сознания позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке форм воздействия. Прежде всего социально-экономическое развитие позволяет оценить значение представляет собой интересный эксперимент системы обучения кадров, соответствующей
  насущным потребностям. С другой стороны сложившаяся структура организации требует анализа новых предложений.Равным образом высокотехнологичная концепция общественной системы способствует подготовке и реализации соответствующих условий активизации. Не
  следует, однако, забывать, что управле
</article>
<footer>
  <p id="copyright" class="content flex">© 123123</p>
</footer>
```

Убрал ваш `div` с классом `container`. Он здесь не нужен